# Prevent Lucene from creating index directory automatically

Tags: java, lucene

I've been reading the *one-time-created-index* with:

```
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
```

where index is

```
    Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "luceneIndex"));
```

`FSDirectory.open()` attempts to create directories, but the production environment is read only.
Is it possible to get the index Directory in read only mode?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code is failing is because by default **FSLockFactory** is used to obtain the lock on the index to prevent corruption. To obtain the lock it creates lock file. Obviously, in your case it's not possible, so you need to use another implementation - **NoLockFactory**.

```
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/tmp/test"), NoLockFactory.INSTANCE);
```